# Visual Studio makefile project not showing errors in editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, arm

I'm using an ARM compiler (RVDS) and using Visual C++ 2005 Express as my IDE because I'm not a fan of the old version of Eclipse that ARM chose. I created a makefile project which builds correctly. Unfortunately when there is a compile error the error shows up in the "Error" pane, but double clicking the error does not open the file in the editor.

In the "Error" pane the correct file is shown, but the line number is blank. Is there a way to get Visual C++ to better parse the error messages to extract the correct line numbers and link the errors to the editor?

**UPDATED:**
Visual C++ parsed the compiler output correctly when I created the solution/project in the same directory as the makefile or build scripts. I only had this problem when the solution/project was created in a different directory than the makefile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past I've used a script that filtered my 3rd-party compiler's error message into the format Visual Studio expects.  I've since lost the scripts (due to not needing them in a while, changin job, etc.).

Here's a mirror of a Microsoft newsgroup posting (I can't find the post in Google Groups) that describes a similar process along with a sed script:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.vc/6Umtwq2XcY0

The relevant information is that the VS build configuration launches the tool and pipes the output through a sed script:

```
CALL mm.bat 2<&1 | sed -u -f ..\..\errfix.sed
```

and the sed script:

```
#------- START errfix.sed
#MPC561 - TYPE:\1 ID:\2 FILE:\3 LINE:\4 POS:\5 REST:\6
s/^(\([EWI]\)) \([A-Z][0-9]*-*[A-Z]*\); "\(.*\)", line \([0-9]*\) pos \([0-9]*\); \(.*\)/\3(\4) : (\1) \2 : \6/
s/(E)/Error/g
s/(W)/Warning/g
s/(I)/Informational/g
s/..\\..\\..\\cu\\//
s/..\\..\\../../
#------- END
```

I imagine the script would need to be tailored to your particular tool - the script looks pretty intimidating at first glance (to me anyway), but I 'd bet it wouldn't be too difficult to get it massage the output to what VS expects.

Comment: In my case `s/^(\([EWI]\)) \([A-Z][0-9]*-*[A-Z]*\); "\(.*\)", line \([0-9]*\) pos` gives:
`sed: file errfix.sed line 2: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: @user3007735: I believe that through a cut-n-paste problem from the original post the first line of the sed script go split in two. Keep in mind that I have no idea what kinds of error messages this sed script was transforming.  The sed script is just an example of how an error message from one tool can be transformed into one that VS can use.

Comment: Yes you are right I corrected it, it is working fine but still VS 08 showing no errors or warnings. :(

Comment: @user3007735: keep in mind that the sed script is written to reformat specific error messages.  If your tool produces different messages (which is likely, since I don't even know what tool the script was written to deal with), then you need a different script.

Comment: @MichaelBurr The link you have provided in this question has now become some form of spam site.

Comment: @Ben: I've updated the link to one that I hope remains valid.  I think the answer stands on its own without the link, so if this one disappears in the future, I'll probably just remove it (giving credit to Ulf Thorsen, who posted the solution I summarize here).

Answer (score 4):

In case someone else trips on this issue.  Here's what I ended up with:

```
make -f $(TargetName).mak  2<&1 | sed -e 's|/cygdrive/\([a-z]\)/|\1:/|' -e 's/\.\([ch]\):\([0-9]*\)/.\1 (\2)/' ; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

This works for gcc error formats of file.c:line#: error desc (e.g. main.c:12: HelloWorld is undefined)

The 2<&1 bit makes sure we capture stderr as well, the first sed substitute replaces cygwin drive mapping back to windows (my case), and the second replaces the :dd: error format with (dd): for files ending with .c or .h.

finally, the exit status of make is maintained through exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]} bit so that visual studio doesn't think build succeeded just because sed succeed.